# Is there a way to split a bounty to multiple answers?

Tags: support

I have a question, where 2 people had really good answers.  Neither was a "direct hit" for what I was looking for, but both sparked good thinking.
Is there a way to split the 200 point bounty to them?
Or must I distribute the bounty to a single "best" answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, you have to pick one answer. In theory there should be a single post that completely answers the question, and if there isn't somebody should write one; you shouldn't need to get pieces of the answer from multiple posts. See the feature request: [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)

Comment: Makes sense.  In the question:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44764/what-windows-related-files-are-valueless-to-nix-users  it is a difficult question with several ways of trying to approach the problem.  In one of the answers, it somewhat disregards some of the premise of the question, and comes up with a pretty good theory.  In the end, there may not be a canonical answer to the question, yet.  And, maybe the question needs a little paraphrasing to more correctly get targeted solutions.